Prepending command with SHELL doesn't work
I have script.sh as below:
MYVAR=world

I then have a Dockerfile as below:
FROM redhat/ubi8
COPY script.sh /script.sh

# Source the script and echo. Expected to see: hello world
RUN source /script.sh && echo hello $MYVAR

# Run echo without sourcing script. Expected to see: hello
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

# Modify SHELL and echo. Expected to see: hello world
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'source /script.sh'", "&&"]
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

The final SHELL and RUN command does not work as expected. My expectation is that ultimately, the final RUN command should be /bin/bash -c 'source /script.sh' && echo hello $MYVAR. Running docker build . --preview plain does indeed indicate that's the command. And, if I run that command on my own command line, it works.
But when I build I get the following error:
#9 [5/5] RUN echo hello $MYVAR
#9 0.194 &&: source /script.sh: No such file or directory
#9 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -c 'source /script.sh' && echo hello $MYVAR" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
------
 > [5/5] RUN echo hello $MYVAR:
0.194 &&: source /script.sh: No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'source /script.sh'", "&&"]
  11 |
  12 | >>> RUN echo hello $MYVAR
  13 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c 'source /script.sh' && echo hello $MYVAR" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127

Why does this SHELL and RUN combination fail to work in my Dockerfile? I've tried other alternatives for the SHELL command, including the following, but none have worked. Most have errored with varying exit codes.
This one does not have an exit code, but the echo doesn't echo anything:
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /script.sh", "&&"]

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "\"source /script.sh\"", "&&"]

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /script.sh &&"]

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'source /script.sh' &&"]

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "\"source /script.sh" &&"]

The following questions are related, but not exact:

Docker build - use the same shell for all RUN commands
Run script before every RUN in Dockerfile?


Why did you add the literal quotes?

It was just one of the options I was playing around it. I was trying to mimic what worked on the command line.

The && and executing multiple commands is a shell syntax not recognized by the kernel's exec syscall. You've also single quoted the 'source /script.sh' command that forces /bin/bash to attempt to execute that single command, rather than sourcing /script.sh.
Even if this did work, the next problem you'd have is that source only applies to the single bash shell instance, and all variables set will no longer be defined when that shell exits and the next command is executed, which means /bin/bash -c "source /script.sh" is mostly a no-op. If you ran that right now from the prompt you'd see that none of the variables exported from that script are defined.
I'd find it easiest to maintain a Dockerfile with chained commands to run in a single run line, like:
FROM redhat/ubi8
COPY script.sh /script.sh

RUN source /script.sh \
 && echo hello $MYVAR \
 && ... more install commands here ...


So then why does executing /bin/bash -c 'source script.sh' && echo hello $MYVAR on the command line print hello world as expected? I know I could put source /script.sh in front of the RUN command, but in my real-world scenario, I need many RUN commands throughout, each of which would need that source preceding it. It's error-prone because it's pretty easy to forget to source the script.

Your command line is processed by a shell, not directly by the kernel exec syscall. And you would have already defined MYVAR in your shell for that to work. You can chain the "many RUN commands" into one.

Okay, thanks for the info. I'm aware I can chain RUN commands, but there are scenarios where non-RUN actions need to happen between RUN commands such that they can't be chained.

Under the hood, a Unix command is a series of words, and low-level system calls like execve(2) take the series of words.  If you use any of the Dockerfile "exec format" JSON-syntax directives (like RUN ["echo", "hello"]) you explicitly specify the sequence of words; the only quoting and escaping that applies is the JSON string quoting.
The default Docker shell setting is SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"].  If you have a "shell" format command like RUN echo hello $MYVAR, internally that string is passed as a single additional argument to the SHELL.
The last part of this riddle is how sh -c actually works.  It takes the next single word from the command line, and runs it as a shell command.  If that single-word command string happens to contain positional parameter references like $0, $1, ... then those refer to any additional arguments after the command string.
So in your setup, when you say
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'source /script.sh'", "&&"]
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

The list of command words is (one word to a line, all punctuation included as part of the argument)
/bin/bash
-c
'source /script.sh'
&&
echo hello $MYVAR

This isn't what you want, in several ways.  The single-quoted 'source /script.sh' is interpreted as a single word because the shell sees the single quotes.  && is passed as a separate parameter and not a shell operator, and both that and the actual command are in positional parameters and not part of the command string.
If you're aware of this syntax you can sort of make it work
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c", ". /script.sh && eval \"$1\"", "sh"]
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

Note that I've used the standard . instead of source, I've filled in a command name to be $0, and I'm explicitly using the RUN string $1 inside the command string.

For what you've shown in the question, to just set a single environment variable, it's far simpler to use Docker primitives
ENV MYVAR=world
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

and leave SHELL alone.  For some specific things like Python virtual environments, you can e.g. just prepend the virtual environment directory to $PATH instead of trying to run the activate script.
If the script really truly is dynamic, there's a simpler pattern of using the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT to first read the script and then run the main container CMD.  In Dockerfile RUN instructions you'd need to explicitly read in the script, as shown in @BMitch's answer.  This is probably simpler and clearer than trying to manipulate SHELL this way.

At the start: "Under the hood, a Unix command is a series of words, and low-level system calls like execve(2) take the series of words." — I've always understood it as ''Under the hood a SHELL command is a series of words'', and reading man execve shows an array of args (words) -- execve does not do parsing, what you give it must have already been parsed into words by the shell or by your program that's calling execve. And there are different shells that parse differently.

In a Docker context, JSON-syntax RUN/CMD/ENTRYPOINT is passed directly as that list of words, and the only parsing that's done is parsing the JSON array.  Shell syntax is passed as a single additional argument to the SHELL.

You can use ARG together with BASH_ENV:
FROM redhat/ubi8
COPY script.sh /script.sh

# Source the script and echo. Expected to see: hello world
RUN source /script.sh && echo hello $MYVAR

# Run echo without sourcing script. Expected to see: hello
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

# Modify SHELL and echo. Expected to see: hello world
ARG BASH_ENV=/script.sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo hello $MYVAR

